# nullpointerexception in a PageFormat variable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel

im trying to print a JPanel with a lot of contents and it's a bit huge and need to know the num of pages and the Page format. But when i try to know these things in a lane crash and i have a nullpointer exception.

this is a short piece of code:

```
private Component componentToBePrinted;
private PageFormat format;
private int numPages;

componentToBePrinted = this.PanelMatricula;
Dimension page = this.componentToBePrinted.getPreferredSize();

numPages = (int) Math.ceil(page.height/format.getImageableY());// Nullpointerexception 
print(componentToBePrinted.getGraphics(), format, this.getNumberOfPages());
```

Im new in the wolrd of the printing and i don't know what's the fail, i researched a lot and don't find any solution.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Your `format` seems like `null`. You need to `initialize` it.

Comment: how i must initialize it? like this.PageFormat or something similar?

Comment: I am not sure how are you using it. so look at [Uses of Class
java.awt.print.PageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/class-use/PageFormat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.ceil(page.height/format.getImageableY());` I am bating `format` is `null`

The [`printerJob.defaultPage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#defaultPage%28%29) function: Creates a new PageFormat instance and sets it to a default size and orientation. And  [`printerJob.getPageFormat(PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#getPageFormat%28javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet%29) calculates a PageFormat with values consistent with those supported by the current PrintService for this job (i.e., the value returned by `getPrintService()`) and media, printable area and orientation contained in attributes.

so, you can use either of them to get the `PageFormat`.

Comment: Yes but i have no idea of how i must initialize PageFormat format.
i tryed to `PageFormat format = new PageFormat()`but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the `PageFormat` `format` is initialized

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat format = job.defaultPage();
```

Read: [A Basic Printing Program](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html)